# JQuery Slick carousel div height

Tags: jquery

I need to get the height of the slides when the plugin is loaded, unfortunately it appears onInit fires before the slide is loaded and returns a height of 0, after the first slide has shown i can call onBeforeChange which gives me the height i need, but only after the first slide has been shown.

```
onBeforeChange:function()
{ 
    $(".slick-slide").each(function()
    {
        var h=($(this).height()-500)/2;
        $(this).css("margin-top",-h);
        $(this).find(".section_title").css("margin-top",h);
        $(this).find(".bullet").css("margin-bottom",h);
    });
}
```

Any suggestions how i can do this at the time the first slide gets its height?

Thanks

Comment: $('document').ready(function(){/*here your function*/});

Comment: Thanks but already tried that, ".slick_slide" still has a height of 0, by using alert($(".slick-slide").height()) and the slide hasn't loaded before the alert box opens.